# Clear the screen right before new data is ready to be displayed while in a loop?

Tags: python

I am using the yfinance library to build a stock ticker that checks a variety of stock prices and their change. I have no problem with that.

The problem I am having is a nicety:  only clearing the screen after I have new data to display (both stocks showing, then cleared, and immediately updated). Here is my current code. I have tried os.system('clear') after time.sleep(1) but there is a delay before the new data has been obtained and displayed. If I try to 'clear' before the print, it clears the first stock before the second is displayed. I even went down the very interesting rabbithole of using ANSI code like print('\033[1A', end='\x1b[2K').

```
    import yfinance as yf
    import time
    import os


    stocks = ["SPY", "TMUS"]

    def check():
        for stock in stocks:
        l = yf.Ticker(stock)
        change = (l.info["regularMarketOpen"] - l.info["bid"])
        if change is not None:
           print(l.info["symbol"],": ", l.info["bid"], f'      Change: %f' % change)

    def main():
        while True:
            check()
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system('clear')
    

    if __name__ == '__main__':
              main()
```

`

I am guessing asynchronous might be the way to go? I haven't played with that yet, and would appreciate any reading if that is the answer.

Comment: I added if stocks.index(stock) == 0:
                os.system('clear')
after if change is not none:  instead of 'clear' in main() and that definitely helped. You can only see the second stock clearing and refreshing. But still not seamless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting all of the stock info into a list, then only clearing the screen after the list was the expected length based on the length of the stocks list. I don't really need the separate functions at this point and I am sure there are cleaner ways to do this. I'll take another look after I have to get up in a couple hours.

```
    import yfinance as yf
    import time
    import os


    stocks = ["SPY", "TMUS", "DAL", "IEF"]
    data = []

    def check():
        for stock in stocks:
            stock = yf.Ticker(stock)
            name = stock.info["symbol"]
            data.append("Symbol: ")
            data.append(name)
            bid = stock.info["bid"]
            data.append("    Current: ")
            data.append(bid)
            change = (stock.info["bid"] - stock.info["open"])
            data.append("     Change: ")
            data.append('%f\n' % change)
        if len(data) == (len(stocks)*6):
            os.system('clear')
        print (''.join(map(str, data)))
        time.sleep(1)

    def main():
        while True:
            check()
            data.clear()
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).